# Inverse Function for an example

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, boundary-conditions, inverse, inverse-function

I have this funtion i would like to calculate the inverse

```
Inverse[Sqrt[1 - Cosh[2 t] + a Sinh[2 t]]]
```

a is positive number.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might be looking for `InverseFunction`; look at the docs and you'll see that `Inverse` refers to taking the inverse of a square matrix.

Also, you'll want to feed `InverseFunction` a (pure) function, where `t` is specified as the argument of the function. A nice way to do this is by using `|->` syntax; see the docs for `Function`.

```
InverseFunction[t |-> Sqrt[1 - Cosh[2 t] + a Sinh[2 t]]]
```

The output comes with a message noting that it's single-valued, and that values may be lost if your function requires a multivalued inverse instead.

EDIT: `Solve`, mentioned in the other answer, is also a good way to approach this! For full solution information, try replacing `Solve` with `Reduce`, but note that the result we be a condition as opposed to a list of rules. Also note that you can include `Assumptions -> a > 0` as an option to `Solve`.

Answer (score 1):

"Inverse" is for square matrices. You can use Solve...

```
Solve[y == Sqrt[1 - Cosh[2 t] + a Sinh[2 t]], t]
```

This returns a number of answers, though of course with the caveat that some solutions may not be found. You can also try Reduce in place of Solve.